# laravel 8 - auth()->factory() { same refresh() and attemp() } is undefind in JWT AuthController

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, jwt

I use JWT for API authentication in Laravel 8.

When I use `auth()->` in my controller , for `factory()` or `attemp()` or anything, Laravel does not know it and says:

`Undefined method 'attempt'.intelephense(1013)`

I don't know what I forgot to include

my AuthController :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\Admin;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login', 'register']]);
    }

    
    public function login(Request $request){
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json($validator->errors(), 422);
        }

        if (! $token = auth()->attempt($validator->validated())) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }

        return $this->createNewToken($token);
    }
.
.
.
.
.
```

and my config/auth.php file :

```
return [

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'api',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],


    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],


    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],
        // Following array is newly added to config
        'otp-user' => [
            'driver' => 'otp-based-auth-provider'
        ],


    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],


    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intelephense has some trouble dealing with some methods in Laravel. You can either ignore it, as it should work or you can call it by:

```
JWTAuth::attempt($validator->validated)
```

It should make the error go away.

Comment: Perfect solution, thank you!.  I had this problem using Tymon\JWTAuth  in Laravel 9 and visual studio code.